# Numpy can't control the changing of the arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
y[:,2] = np.ravel(rkf78(neq,ti,(ti-step),(step/50),tetol,x1))
```

If I print `x1` before and after this line I get different results. More specifically, the value of `x1` after this line is equal to `y[:,2]`

```
y[:,2] = np.ravel(rkf78(neq,ti,(ti-step),(step/50),tetol,(np.copy(x1))))
```

I found this solution but this thing about arrays changing seems to cause me a lot of troubles. Can anybody suggest me a good explanation about this matter with numpy arrays?

Comment: There are too many unknown variables in those expressions.  But I'm guessing that `rkf78` is changing the `x1` input.  Arguments are passed to functions by reference, and changes inside the function can appear in the variable outside it.

Answer (score 1):

Well without seeing your rkf78 function, it will be hard to see how your x1 list is being used. I'm also assuming x1 is a list or numpy array.

The thing about lists and arrays is that when you set one equal to another, i.e.

```
dummy_list = x1
```

where x1 is your list, any changes made to `dummy_list` will be reflected in `x1` since you didn't make an independent copy, only created a new reference to the old one.  That's why `np.copy(x1)` probably worked; this creates a list with a new memory id and any changes made to this list will not be reflected in `x1`.

Another solution:

```
from copy import deepcopy
dummy_list = deepcopy(x1)
```

essentially does the same thing as before, but also accounts for lists within lists. This cannot be used with arrays though.

For future reference please add a little more information about the elements of your code that are involved with the problem.

Comment: If `x1` is a numpy array (as opposed to a list of lists) `np.copy` is sufficient.  There's no special deepcopy method for arrays.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj, I will change my answer to reflect that